# Integration with respect to Dirac measure using a step function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I have troubles to prove that $\int f(x) d\delta_x(A)=f(x)$ using a step function like $g(x)=\sum_i c_i \mathbb{1_{A_i}}(x) $.

I have tried this :

$$\int g(x)d\delta_x(A)=\int \sum_i c_i \mathbb{1_{A_i}}(x) d \delta_x(A)=\sum_i c_i\int  \mathbb{1_{A_i}}(x) d \delta_x(A)=\sum_i c_i\int_ \mathbb{{A_i}}d \delta_x(A)$$

And as we know in general that $\int_A dP(x)= P(A)$ we get something like this (This is where I get confused):

$$\int g(x)d\delta_x(A)=\sum_i c_i\delta_ \mathbb{{A_i}}(A)$$

which doesn't lead to the result $\int g(x)d\delta_x(A)=g(x)$

Any comments? Help? Thank you

Comment: Are you defining $\delta_x$ as the measure $\delta_x(A)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Exactly, should I edit the question?

Comment: No, that's fine, I was just trying to make it clear how you were defining $\delta_x$. More commonly what you wrote would be the definition.

Comment: In your expression $\int f(x)d\delta_x(A)$ the first appearance of $x$ concerns a variable and the second concerns a fixed point. That is not okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** to make things more clear.

---

Let $x$ be **fixed**.

Then $\delta_x$ denotes a measure wich is prescribed by $A\mapsto 1_A(x)$ on measurable sets $A$.

So by definition $\delta_x(A)=1_A(x)$ for measurable sets $A$.

For every measure $\mu$ and every measurable set $A$ the following notations are used to denote an integral over a characteristic function:

- $\int1_Ad\mu=\mu(A)$
- $\int_Ad\mu=\mu(A)$
- $\int1_A(y)d\mu(y)=\mu(A)$

Applying that on $\delta_x$ we get

- $\int1_Ad\delta_x=\delta_x(A)$
- $\int_Ad\delta_x=\delta_x(A)$
- $\int1_A(y)d\delta_x(y)=\delta_x(A)$

For step function $g$ prescribed by $y\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}1_{A_{i}}\left(y\right)$
we find:

$$\int g\left(y\right)d\delta_{x}\left(y\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\int1_{A_{i}}\left(y\right)d\delta_{x}\left(y\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\delta_{x}\left(A_{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}1_{A_{i}}\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$$

Comment: $\delta_x(A)$ is written for a fixed $A$ and has $x$ as an argument. This implies that $\int_{A_i} d\delta_x(y)=\delta_{A_i}(y)$ right? It's as in $\int_A dP(x)=P(A)$ because $x$ is the argument

Comment: No, here it is as $\int_AdP(y)=P(A)$. This with $dP(y)$ standing for $d\delta_x(y)$. We don't have $\int_Ad\delta_x(y)=\delta_A(y)$ but we have  $\int_Ad\delta_x(y)=\delta_x(A)=1_A(x)$.

Comment: If we set $P(y)=\delta_y(A)$, for both $y$ is the argument. Just as you wrote $\delta_x(A)=1_A(x)$ where $x$ is the argument. Then we have $\int_B dP(y)=P(B)$ and $\int_B d\delta_y(A)=\delta_B(A)$, this is how I see it, what is wrong with it? Thank you

Comment: An integral can only be taken with respect to a measure. If notation $\int_BdP(y)$ is used for the integral then $P$ is this measure. In that line: if you write $\int_Bd\delta_y(A)$ then can you tell me: how is that measure defined here?

Comment: $\delta_x(A)=1_A(x)$. In LHS $A$ is argument and $x$ is fixed. Then $\delta_x$ is a measure hence integrals with respect to it can be taken. In RHS $x$ is argument and $A$ is fixed. In an effort to take integrals you seem to use (wrongly) the RHS.

Comment: That is clear now! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to show $\int_X f d \delta_x=f(x)$. First consider a simple function $s=\sum_i c_i 1_{A_i}$ where the $A_i$ are disjoint. For convenience we can assume WLOG that $\bigcup A_i=X$ (by taking a $c_i$ to be zero if need be). Then there is exactly one $i$ with $x \in A_i$, call this $i(x)$. Then $\int_X s d \delta_x = c_{i(x)} \delta_x(A_{i(x)})=c_{i(x)}=s(x)$. Now extend in the usual way.